# CSS won't display properly on WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

[My WordPress site](http://www.bestalljobs.com) is not properly displaying CSS.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: @Yuval: That's what I thought too. But the link really does go to a site that appears to have no CSS formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS file referenced is `http://www.bestalljobs.com/wp-content/w3tc/min/97618f3fcd22e8979a75a7dd6c414172.3938259878.css`. When I load this into the browser, I get an 'invalid parameter' error.

It's hard to say exactly what you're doing here. Where did you get this URL?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CSS is referenced using the WordPress function [bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo).

It should look something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

It will give the CSS relative to whichever theme is activated. It seems like you have fixed it and you may have used this code initially, but if you have hard coded it in, then change it to this method.

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your header file

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```